# Getting Specific Values from JSON with multiple values from one array with Node.js

Tags: node.js, arrays, json

```js
  let items = [{
  "success": true,
  "item_count": 3,
  "items": {
      "1": ["Item1", "IT1", 43689, -1, 231, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1],
      "2": ["Item2", "IT2", 71362, -1, 78913, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1],
      "3": ["item3", "IT3", 1312, 9123, 3144, 4, 2, -1, -1, -1],
  }
  }];
```

I want to search for example "IT2", and if it was found it returns all other values along with it.

Is there anyway it could be done?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

far to weird to explain but if helps here you go

```
let items = [{
    "success": true,
    "item_count": 3,
    "items": {
        "1": ["Item1", "IT1", 43689, -1, 231, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1],
        "2": ["Item2", "IT2", 71362, -1, 78913, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1],
        "3": ["item3", "IT3", 1312, 9123, 3144, 4, 2, -1, -1, -1],
    }
}];

function findByFilter(filter) {
    const keys = Object.keys(items[0].items);
    let found;
    for(let i = 0; i < keys.length; i++) {
        const valueInIteration = items[0].items[keys[i]];
        if (valueInIteration[1] === filter)
        {
            found = valueInIteration
            break;
        }
    }
    return found;
}

console.log(findByFilter('IT2'));
```